# How do I get Post Object data form Wordpress ACF - Flexible Content field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Using Advanced custom field plugin I have a custom post type that has various custom fields assigned to it.

I'm trying to output all of the data that is contained in the flexible content field "content"

I have it outputting "text_ad" ok but for some reason i can't figure our the "newsletter_article" which is a post object - Any direction to getting this working would be amazing.

Read this https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/ and this https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/

```
<?php
// check if the flexible content field has rows of data
if( have_rows('content') ):

 // loop through the rows of data
while ( have_rows('content') ) : the_row();

    if( get_row_layout() == 'text_ad' ):

        echo the_sub_field('text_ad_title');
        echo the_sub_field('text_ad_url');
        echo the_sub_field('text_ad_description');

    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'newsletter_article' ): 

        $post_object = get_sub_field('the_newsletter_article');
            if( $post_object ):
                   $post = $post_object;
                   setup_postdata( $post );?>
                   <strong><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong>

           <?php 
           wp_reset_postdata();
           endif;

    endif;

endwhile;

else :

// no layouts found

endif;
?>
```

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your ACF setup. Row layouts should be the name of the flexible content type.

Answer (score 0):

Because I'am just getting one object I can access the data like this.

```
<?php
    elseif( get_row_layout() == 'newsletter_article' ): 


        $post_object = get_sub_field('the_newsletter_article');
        $newstitle = $post_object->post_title;
        $newsdescription = $post_object->post_content;
        ?>

        <div style="background-color: #cccccc; margin:0 0 20px 0;">
         <p><strong><?php echo $newstitle; ?></strong></p>
         <p><?php echo $newsdescription; ?></p>
        </div>

   <?php endif; ?>
```